# AWS Federated User Mapping

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, active-directory, amazon-iam

I am trying to identify which active directory users are able to federate to AWS IAM roles. Where is the mapping from Windows Active Directory to IAM Roles stored? Is this stored within IAM or a file outside of AWS?

I have identified the AWS roles which are federated to but can't identify which active directory users are able to log in using those roles.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get this information from AWS. This mapping is done in your SAML solution. It is common to map AWS role with AD group, if you know the group you can see who is member, these members are the ones with access to this role.

Comment: When you say "no way", you mean - the AD groups mapping to the IAM Role, right? not - which users are members in the group (obviously this is also impossible to do from AWS...)

Comment: Exactly, using AWS API's both can't be done.